# Not able to query DFP with Python and DFP API

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, google-dfp

I am using Python 2.7 and the DFP API to read and write to DFP. I had to recently format my Macbook and now have OS Sierra 10.12.6 as well as Python 2.7 on it. I installed googleads as well. I also have the .p12 key needed to get service level access to DFP via the API. It is in the same folder as my scripts. All of this was working before I formatted my machine, but now I am not able to run the scripts and get an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "authorization.py", line 52, in <module>
    main(service_account_email, key_file, application_name)
  File "authorization.py", line 39, in main
    oauth2.GetAPIScope('dfp'), service_account_email, key_file)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/googleads/oauth2.py", line 249, in __init__
    self._FILE_NOT_FOUND_TEMPLATE % key_file)
googleads.errors.GoogleAdsValueError: The specified key file (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/dfp) does not exist.
```

I installed OAuth2 as well, but I'm not sure what the issue is. The Path to the file containing all the DFP service account credentials is also correct.

Can anybody let me know what the issue is?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share your python scripts?

Comment: hi gernberg. I resolved it. Turns out Googleads 11 and above do not accept p12 API Key. They only do JSON and I needed to use p12. So I had to downgrade Googleads to 10.1.0 and it started working. Thank you for writing back!